# regex for tokenizing words and punctuation

Tags: regex, perl, tokenize

I have been tokenizing English strings with a simple `\b` split. However, given the string `Hello, "Joe!"`, a split on `\b` gives back these tokens:

```
print join "\n", split /\b/, 'Hello, "Joe!"';
Hello
, "
Joe
!"
```

I need separate punctuation to be separate tokens. What I need is this list below:

```
print join "\n", split /awesome regex here/, 'Hello, "Joe!"';
Hello
,
"
Joe
!
"
```

I can process the whitespace afterwards, but I can't think of a quick regex way to split the string properly. Any ideas?

#### EDIT

A better test case is `"Hello there, Joe!"`, since it checks that words are split correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?=\W)|(?<=\W)|\s+
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fX3oF6/4

Comment: This works perfectly. Post-processing is necessary to ignore the whitespace elements.

Comment: Not really. Test with `'Hello - World'` as input and see what you get.

Comment: @anubhava It splits that just fine into `Hello, -, World`, albeit with two space entries, which I said I can remove via post-processing. What are you getting?

Comment: @vks you can put `\s+|` on there and it will make post-processing of whitespace unneeded.

Comment: Yes adding `|\s+` was the right fix though this answer became very similar to mine now :)

Comment: Actually, adding `|\s+` at the end doesn't fix it. It has to be `\s+|` at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lookarounds regex to get this:

```
print join "\n", split /\s+|(?=\p{P})|(?<=\p{P})/, 'Hello, "Joe!"';
```

**Output:**

```
Hello
,
"
Joe
!
"
```

`\p{P}` matches any punctuation character.

Example 2:

```
print join "\n", split /\s+|(?=\p{P})|(?<=\p{P})/, 'hello there, Joe!';
hello
there
,
Joe
!
```

Comment: As is this doesn't split "hello there, Joe!" correctly

Comment: Check my updated answer. It is now working with both the inputs.

Comment: Works great, even removes the spaces! Although the Punct class doesn't get the nine characters `[$+<=>^`|~] `. Switching out for `XPosixPunct` or `[[:punct:]]` makes it better.

Comment: Yes `/\s+|(?=[[:punct:]])|(?<=[[:punct:]])/` can also work but I think `[[:punct:]]` won't support unicode punctuations.

Answer (score 1):

Do matching instead of splitting.

```
[A-Za-z]+|[^\w\s]
```

Comment: Almost; it doesn't split `!"`. `print "$1\n" while 'Hello there, "Joe!"' =~ m/([A-Za-z]+|[^\w\s]+)/g;`

Comment: Works great now. Thanks. I think the first char class would be better replaced with a `\w` to work with Unicode words better.